# How to solve the web cannot scan my computer cpu and ram?

Tags: google-chrome, cpu

I want to participate the TOEFL iBT TELXML in the ProctorU. 
However, it reports the error like this:

```
Camera Height: Your Camera Height could not be found.

Camera Width: Your Camera Width could not be found.

Monitor width: [PASSING] Minimum width is 640px. You have 2048px.

Monitor height: [PASSING] Minimum height is 480px. You have 1152px.

Monitor count: [FAILING] You may only use 1 monitor during your exam. Your monitor count could not be found.

CPU Model Name:

CPU Core Count: Your CPU Core Count could not be found.

CPU Architecture: Your CPU Architecture could not be found.

CPU usage: [FAILING] Maximum usage is 95%. Your current usage could not be found.

RAM size: [FAILING] Minimum size is 1 GB. Your size could not be found.

RAM Usage: [FAILING] Maximum usage is 100%. Your current usage could not be found.

Download speed: [FAILING] Minimum speed is 768 kbps. Your speed could not be found.

Upload speed: [FAILING] Minimum speed is 384 kbps. Your speed could not be found.

Browser: Chrome

Browser version: [PASSING] The minimum version for Chrome is 35. You have 81.0.4044.138.

Operating system: Windows

OS version: [PASSING] The minimum version for Windows is 04. You have 10.

User agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/81.0.4044.138 Safari/537.36

Extension version: Your Extension Version could not be found.

Connection to ProctorU video servers: Fail

Workflow: [PASSING] Your system supports your institution's exam workflows.
```

The system cannot scan my computer cpu and its architecture. How to solve it? Thanks.

Comment: I would contact your institution's IT department for assistance.

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks, I have solve the problem.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the author indicated they already solved the problem in a comment.